# What's the purpose and advantage of declaration in TypeScript? Can you prove them in examples?

Tags: typescript

Since the compiler doesn't compile declaration into js file, I just don't see the purpose of using declaration in TypeScript. Can somebody explain its purpose and advantages for me please!

Comment: The compiler checks the types in an attempt to stop you from making mistakes. If they’re correct, there’s no need to include them in the JavaScript output because they won’t be anything unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Think of them as the meta-data of the libraries you're using.

They are what allows the compiler to know whether you're code is valid or not.

Plus they are what gives you a rich development environment, they give type information to the underlying tooling to provide you with intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

### The purpose

**The purpose** of declaration files in Typescript separate the type definitions into a different file for the purpose of not bloating your JavaScript files with statements that will not render in your JS.

Another purpose of the declaration files is to follow a already proven concept of separating the definition of the statements ( metadata ) in a separate file. Languages like C ( `.h` - Header files ) are using similar concept.

### The advantage

**The advantage** is that you can reuse those definition files across your platform without polluting ( again ) your javascript files. Imagine an app that uses NodeJS as a back-end and BackboneJS as a front-end framework. You will most probably need to reuse some object declarations in the two applications, so you will just include the declaration file for the reused part.

Even if you don't use JS as your back-end and front-end language you can safely separate the structure of your application and make out of it a documentation basis. There are tools like [typedoc.io](http://typedoc.io) that can actually separate it and produce a nice documentation out of your declaration files.